# Version conflict in Weblogic 10.3.6 configuration in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to configure Weblogic 10.3.6 server in eclipse Luna. But I could not configure as the eclipse looking for weblogic 10.3.0 but I have the version 10.3.6.

The path "C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3" contains the wrong version of WebLogic Server. Expected version 10.0. Found version 10.3.6.

I don't find any specific adaptor/plugin for weblogic 10.3.6. I want to configure 10.3.6 in eclipse Luna. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse and you will have the option for all version of WebLogic. This link has the download for Luna:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html

Comment: I downloaded the latest version OEPE 12.1.3.4. I have this problem in that version of eclipse/oepe.

Comment: So do you see all of the WebLogic versions as options, but when you point to your install folder you get this message? Do you have just one version of WebLogic installed?

Comment: Only Weblogic 9.2, 10.0 are available in OEPE Luna. Yes, I get this error when I point to the installation directory. Yes, I have only 10.3 installed in my machine.

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: I use the java version jdk 160_29

Comment: Although WebLogic 10.3.6 can run using JDK 1.6 or 1.7, it could be that this plugin requires JDK 1.7. I would give that a try.